# How to calculate a required sample size for an estimate of the population total $\tau$ without knowing the population variance $\sigma^2$

Tags: sample-size

To calculate a required sample size $n$ for estimating the population total $\tau$ (which is equal to $N\mu$) with a pre-specified error bound $B$, the formula is:

$$n = \frac {N\sigma^2}{(N-1)\frac{B^2}{4N^2} - \sigma^2}$$

where $N$ is the population size, $\sigma^2$ is the population variance, and the error bound $B$ equals $2\sqrt{\hat v(\hat \tau)}$, where $\hat v(\hat \tau)$ is the estimated variance of the population total $\tau$.

In many cases, we don't have knowledge of the population variance, but there are ways to make an informed guess (e.g., dividing the range of the data by 4).

However, assume that we do have knowledge about a population proportion. For example, consider a population with size $N$ = 10,000. In this population, we can reasonably guess that 30% smoke cigarettes and 70% do not. With these data, I want to calculate the required sample size $n$ to estimate the population total $\tau$ of cigarette smokers, with an error bound $B$ of 150.

Given that we don't have knowledge about the population variance, we cannot use the formula given above.  However, my question is whether we can instead calculate the required sample size for estimating a population proportion $p$:

$$n = \frac {Npq}{(N-1)\frac{B^2}{4} - pq}$$

where $p = 0.3$ and $q = p-1 = 0.7$.

Is it possible to use this formula to calculate the required sample size for estimating $\tau$? We would get:

$$n = \frac {10000(.3)(.7)}{(9999)\frac {(150/10000)^2}{4} - (.3)(.7)} = 5958.397 \approx 5959$$

From this answer, I would then assume that even though I calculated the required sample size for the *population proportion* with a given error bound, this sample size is also applicable for estimating the *population total* with the same given error bound.

Is my reasoning correct? Thank you!